# C# run WMI query against multiple computers

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to run a simple WMI query in C# using System.Management but I would like it to target multiple remote computers instead of just a single one; either one at a time or all at once.

I have users currently query our active directory and return computer names inside a textbox.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this ? i tried a for each loop but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: -1 ... _but it doesn't seem to work_.  Step through it and tell us how it isn't working.

Comment: It says RPC server is offline but without the foreach loop on a single machine, it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually have the proper user rights to access WMI remotely:

http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enableWMI.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, silly mistake, my for loops was in the wrong place.